# How to count documents in Elasticsearch with exclusive name-value attribute filters of nested type?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-painless

`Require a solution to count the number of documents in Elasticsearch that match a given set of exclusive name-value attribute pairs, where the attribute field is of nested type. The output should show the count of documents that satisfy each attribute filter separately. If a document satisfies one filter but not another, it should still be considered for the count of the satisfied filter.

Example Data in Elasticsearch:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 9,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.0020497,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "INDEX",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "DOC_1",
        "_score": 1.0020497,
        "_source": {
          "doc": {
            "attributes": [
              {
                "name": "NAME_1",
                "value": "VALUE_1"
              },
              {
                "name": "NAME_2",
                "value": "VALUE_2"
              },
              {
                "name": "NAME_3",
                "value": "VALUE_3"
              }
            ],
            "unique_doc_id": "DOC_1"
          }
        }
      }
        {
        "_index": "INDEX",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "DOC_2",
        "_score": 1.0020497,
        "_source": {
          "doc": {
            "attributes": [
              {
                "name": "NAME_1",
                "value": "VALUE_1"
              },
              {
                "name": "NAME_2",
                "value": "VALUE_7"
              },
              {
                "name": "NAME_4",
                "value": "VALUE_6"
              }
            ],
            "unique_doc_id": "DOC_2"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Example Input:

```
{
  "attributes": [
    {
      "name": "NAME_1",
      "value": "VALUE_1"
    },
    {
      "name": "NAME_2",
      "value": "VALUE_7"
    },
    {
      "name": "NAME_3",
      "value": "VALUE_30"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "attribute_name": "NAME_1",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "attribute_name": "NAME_2",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "attribute_name": "NAME_3",
    "count": 0
  }
]
```

Tried to write the script using painless script. The main problem in this was having a global variable which could store and increase the count whenever a filter got satisfied.
`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use one aggregation for each condition you want to check. Each aggregation must be at the same level, so each condition will be checked individually. This would be an example of the query:

```
GET /index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "Filter by NAME_1": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "attributes",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "attributes.name": "NAME_1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "attributes.value": "VALUE_1"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Filter by NAME_2": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "attributes",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "attributes.name": "NAME_2"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "attributes.value": "VALUE_7"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Filter by NAME_3": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "attributes",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "attributes.name": "NAME_3"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "attributes.value": "VALUE_30"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output would be something like that:

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "Filter by NAME_1" : {
      "doc_count" : 2
    },
    "Filter by NAME_2" : {
      "doc_count" : 1
    },
    "Filter by NAME_3" : {
      "doc_count" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you still have this issue? Did the solution work for you or there is anymore you can ask?